# Allow text between 2 non contenteditable contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div contenteditable>` and 2 divs with `contenteditable="false"`. When I  set the cursor between them to add text, it does not let me. I want to be able to write text between them. I fix the poblem by adding a `<span>&nbsp;</span>`. But if I backspace, the `<span>&nbsp;</span>` can get deleted and get back to the same problem. If I do `<span contenteditable="false">&nbsp;</span>` I won't be able to add texts.

How to fix that problem definitively?

**Note:** the codes inside the div#editable aren't static, they are dynamic. I(the user) can add a span, div, p, h1, any Html Element I want.

Code:

```
<div contenteditable>
    <div contenteditable=false></div><div contenteditable=false></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
this.divNew.children().each(function () {
    var child = $(this);
    if (!child.is("br")) {
        child.after($("<span>").addClass("gvwb-span-empty-newline").append("&nbsp;"));
    }
});
```

```js
$("#editable").children().each(function () {
    var child = $(this);
    if (!child.is("br")) {
        child.after($("<span>").addClass("gvwb-span-empty-newline").append("&nbsp;"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable" contenteditable style="border: 1px solid black;">
    Hello world<br>
    <div contenteditable="false" style="height: 10px; background: blue"></div><div contenteditable="false" style="height: 10px; background: red"></div>
        Hello world 2 <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an empty `<div>` in between the two non-editable.
Just set its height to 1em with CSS.

```js
/*
$("#editable").children().each(function () {
        var child = $(this);
        if (!child.is("br")) {
            child.after($("<span>").addClass("gvwb-span-empty-newline").append("&nbsp;"));
        }
    });
*/
```

```css
#editable>div:nth-of-type(2){
  height:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable" contenteditable style="border: 1px solid black;">
  Hello world<br>
  <div contenteditable="false" style="height: 10px; background: blue"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div contenteditable="false" style="height: 10px; background: red"></div>
  Hello world 2 <br>
</div>
```

Comment: You should note, the codes inside the div#editable aren't static, they are dynamic. I(the user) can add a span, div, p, h1, any Html Element I want.